# Fetch data from Server using Jquery AJAX and then trying to make a url using Jinja 2 format

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get data using API from the server and then render it in Jinja2 template page but i dont know how to pass the item.id in it. the code is below:

```
$.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product",function(data){
                $.each(data,function(index,item){
                    var obj="<div class='col-lg-3'>"+
                        "<div class='card shop-hover'>"+
                        "<img src="+item.image[0]+" style='height:250px;' alt='wrapkit' class='img-fluid' />"+
                        "<div class='card-img-overlay align-items-center'>"+
                        "<a href='{% url 'Checkout' item.id %}' class='btn btn-md btn-info-gradiant'>Buy Now</a>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "<span class='label label-rounded label-success'>Sale</span>"+"</div>"+
                        "<div class='card'>"+
                        "<h6><a href='#' class='link'>"+item.Name+"</a></h6>"+
                        "<h6 class='subtitle'>"+item.BottomHeading+"</h6>"+
                        "<h5 class='font-medium m-b-30'>"+item.UnitPrice+" / <del class='text-muted line-through'>$225</del></h5>"+
                        "</div>"+
                        "</div>";
                    $(".shop-listing").append(obj);
                });
            });
```

And this is the line of code where i am getting trouble

```
"<a href='{% url 'Checkout' item.id %}' class='btn btn-md btn-info-gradiant'>Buy Now</a>"
```

Comment: could you please share the code for your views.py and urls.py

Comment: This is URL.py


path('Checkout/<id>', views.Checkout,name="Checkout")

and View.py is a simple page returning list

def ListProducts(request):
    return render(request,'listing.htm')

it is saying that the reverse for the url not found

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the full url name like so

```
"<a href='http://127.0.0.1:8000/Checkout/" + item.id + "' class='btn btn-md btn-info-gradiant'>Buy Now</a>"
```